# Function is not printing out the result

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have to make a function which concatenates two strings but I have to add a '\n' after the first word. I figured everything out and for some reason it doesn't print out anything. Any ideas? It probably has to do something with the pointers. I just can't get my head around them. Here's the code.

```
char *function(char *s1, char *s2){
    char *newStr;
    int size;
    size = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

    newStr = (char *)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));

    while(*s1!= '\0'){
        *newStr = *s1;
        newStr++;
        s1++;
    }
    *newStr = '\n';
    newStr++;
    while(*s2 != '\0'){
        *newStr = *s2;
        newStr++;
        s2++;
    }
    *newStr = '\0';
return newStr;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *str1 = "Hello";
    char *str2 = "World";

    printf("%s",function(str1, str2));

     return 0;
}
```

So as a result I should get:

```
Hello
World
```

but I'm not getting anything back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to the end of the buffer rather than a pointer to the start of the buffer. Look at the last two lines of the function:

```
*newStr = '\0';
return newStr;
```

Clearly this returns a pointer to the null `char`, i.e. the empty string.

Solve the problem by introducing a temporary pointer which you will use to step through the output buffer. Then you can return the pointer to the beginning of the output buffer.

```
char *function(char *s1, char *s2){
    int size = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 2;//one for '\n', one for '\0'
    char *result = malloc(size);
    char *p = result;

    while(*s1 != '\0'){
        *p = *s1;
        p++;
        s1++;
    }
    *p = '\n';
    p++;
    while(*s2 != '\0'){
        *p = *s2;
        p++;
        s2++;
    }
    *p = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

You also need to allocate an extra char for the `\n`, as shown above. Finally, your calling code never frees the memory allocated by `function`.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I get a warning at *p = result saying "Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast."

Comment: No, it works fine. You must have mis-copied. For example: http://ideone.com/jQhMj

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at two things:

- how much space you're allocating for the new string, and compare that with how many characters you're actually writing to that string.
- where in the string your returned pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

You return from `function()` a pointer to the last element in the allocated `char[]` – instead of returning the pointer to the first element.

Every time you do `newStr++;` you increase the actual pointer you later return. to solve it you can do one of these:

1. create a copy of the pointer `newStr`, which is initialized to be the same as `newStr` and increase it - leave `newStr` as it is.
2. create an index [let it be `i`] and increase it, and use `newStr[i]` to access the allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged the code for you. Here is the debugged code:

```
char *function(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *newStr, *str;
    int size;
    size = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

    newStr = (char *) malloc((size + 2) * sizeof(char));
    str = newStr;
    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        *(newStr++) = *(s1++);
    }
    *newStr = '\n';
    newStr++;
    while (*s2 != '\0') {
        *newStr = *s2;
        newStr++;
        s2++;
    }
    *newStr = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *str1 = "Hello";
    char *str2 = "World";

    printf("%s", function(str1, str2));

    return 0;
}
```

The actual problem was that as you incremented newStr until the last, when you returned it from `function()` it was pointing to the end of the buffer. ie `'\0'`. That is why it didn't show up. Now In the above code I have introduced a variable `str` that points at the beginning of the string `newStr`.

Hope you understood..

Peace...